# Dynamics Nav (Navision) webservice ReadMultiple date filter

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

Using the Navision webservices, how can you filter by a date.

i.e. Within a SalesHeader table there is an "ExportedDate". I would like to find all SalesHeaders where the ExportedDate has not been set or were exported on a particular date.

It seems that whenever we set a filter on a date field, then the webservice will either return all rows or no rows.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done. You have to use the same filter expression as you would use in the Nav Client:

```
01012011..         would be all dates from 01.01.2011
..01012011         would be all dates to 01.01.2011
01012011..03012011 gets all dates between 01. and 03.
```

Comment: I'm dealing with this problem. Our dates in Last_Modified_Date on a page looks like this: 2013-04-09

When doing as explained in the answer nothing is returned:

        array(
            'Field' => 'Last_Date_Modified',
            'Criteria' => '20130101..'
        )
Any clues as to what to do?

Comment: In case someone sees this, I have a posted a new question regarding a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542364/date-filter-in-microsoft-dynamics-nav-webservice

Answer (score 1):

After publishing page 42 (Sales Order) as a web service in NAV, I added a web reference to the newly created web service in my Visual Studio project. In the C# code, I create a new instance of the service, and tell it to use the default credentials:

```
SalesOrders_Service salesOrdersService = new SalesOrders_Service();
salesOrdersService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Then I instantiate a filter, and set the field and criteria:

```
SalesOrders_Filter filter = new SalesOrders_Filter();
filter.Field = SalesOrders_Fields.Document_Date;
filter.Criteria = "01-31-14|''"; // specific date (MM-dd-yy) or empty
```

The filter instance is then added to a new array of SalesOrders_Filters before passing the latter to ReadMultiple:

```
SalesOrders[] salesOrders = salesOrdersService.ReadMultiple(new SalesOrders_Filter[] { filter }, null, 0);
```

On my machine, this returns two orders whose Document Date is 31 January 2014, and one order with a blank Document Date.

Comment: Great! its working for filter array by the concatenation '|' symbol