# Filtration for navision web services in android

Tags: android, android-ksoap2, wsdl2java, dynamics-nav

How to pass filter in navision web services calling from android devices and how to fetch data?
I've called the web services using WSDL & ksoap2 with NTML authentication and successfully fetching data, but filter does not work when applied.

Comment: Described [here with xml sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542364/date-filter-in-microsoft-dynamics-nav-webservice) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423017/dynamics-nav-navision-webservice-readmultiple-date-filter).

Comment: I'd gone through these links before, and the issue was between Vector Object and the soapObject. Anyway I solved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you post solution then?

Answer (score 0):

**ADDING THIS TO THE WHERE METHOD IS BEING CALLED**

```
        VectorApp_Setup_Filter vfilter = new VectorApp_Setup_Filter();

        App_Setup_Filter appsetupFilter1 = new App_Setup_Filter();
        appsetupFilter1.field = App_Setup_Fields.Salesperson_Code;
        Log.e("SALES CODE PASSING IN FILTER ", editStrOfflineUserId);
        appsetupFilter1.criteria = editStrOfflineUserId;

        App_Setup_Filter appsetupFilter2 = new App_Setup_Filter();
        appsetupFilter2.field = App_Setup_Fields.Status;
        appsetupFilter2.criteria = "Intrasit";

        vfilter.add(appsetupFilter2);
        vfilter.add(appsetupFilter1);

        appsetup.ReadMultipleAsync(vfilter, null, 0);
```

**READMULTIPLE ASYNC METHOD**

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject(
            "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/app_setup", "ReadMultiple");

    for (int i = 0; i < filter.size(); i++) {

        soapReq.addProperty("filter", getSOAPVectorAppsetup(filter, i));

    }

    soapReq.addProperty("bookmarkKey", bookmarkKey);
    soapReq.addProperty("setSize", setSize);
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);
```

**METHOD DETAILS :- getSOAPVectorAppsetup();**

```
private SoapObject getSOAPVectorAppsetup(VectorApp_Setup_Filter filter,
        int position) {
    SoapObject appsetup = new SoapObject(
            "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/app_setup", "anyType");

    // for (int i = 0; i < filter.size(); i++) {

    Log.e("Field", 0 + "" + filter.get(position).getProperty(0));
    Log.e("Criteria", 0 + " " + filter.get(position).getProperty(1));

    appsetup.addPropertyIfValue("Field", filter.get(position)
            .getProperty(0));
    appsetup.addPropertyIfValue("Criteria", filter.get(position)
            .getProperty(1));

    // }

    return appsetup;

}
```

This Solution Worked For ME.