# Filter Navision WebService in Android for ReadMultiple Method

Tags: android, filter, navision

I have called navision web service succesfully by authenticating it through the use of NTML authentication protocol. And i also got the full, Proper data for all the Method but i have issue in calling READ MULTIPLE METHOD with Filter. i have passed filter in below manner.

```
CustomerList_Filter customFilter = new CustomerList_Filter();
customFilter.field = CustomerList_Fields.Name;
customFilter.criteria = "B*";
VectorCustomerList_Filter vfilter = new VectorCustomerList_Filter();
vfilter.add(customFilter);
custService.ReadMultipleAsync(vfilter, null,0);
```

Eventhough i passes Filter to get Customer name Record  starting with B letter still it shows all customer. & custService is an object of CustomerList_Service class.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[It is said](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477110.aspx) that first parameter of ReadMultiple is array. Is VectorCustomerList_Filter an array? Maybe you should write `custService.ReadMultipleAsync(vfilter.ToArray(), null,0);`

Also you can try to put code the way [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817067/1820340). `salesOrdersService.ReadMultiple(new SalesOrders_Filter[] { filter }, null, 0);`

If this not helps then try to catch output XML message that is sent as request to web service. You'll be able to find error by analyzing it.

Comment: Mak thnx for your reply i solved it in this way Actually the issue i faced was i am passing VECTOR object in SOAP REQUEST where as i have to pass the SOAPOBJECT in SOAP REQUEST.